# Facebook app invite in Android using Cordova no callback received for dialog onSuccess/onCancel/onError

Tags: android, cordova, facebook-app-invites

I have attached the trigger point code for Facebook App invite dialog.I get callback for `onActivityResult` but the callback will not be received for the app invite callbacks registered using facebook callback registers. I have tried the same code in native working perfectly fine.But when i develop cordova plugin for android platform facing issue with the callback.PLEASE HELP

```
    if (AppInviteDialog.canShow()) {
        AppInviteContent.Builder builder = new AppInviteContent.Builder();
        builder.setApplinkUrl(url);
        if (picture != null) {
            builder.setPreviewImageUrl(picture);
        }

        showDialogContext = callbackContext;
        PluginResult pr = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.NO_RESULT);
        pr.setKeepCallback(true);
        showDialogContext.sendPluginResult(pr);

        cordova.setActivityResultCallback(this);
        AppInviteDialog appInviteDialog = new AppInviteDialog(cordova.getActivity());
        appInviteDialog.show(builder.build());
        appInviteDialog.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<AppInviteDialog.Result>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(AppInviteDialog.Result result) {
                if (showDialogContext != null) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
                        Bundle bundle = result.getData();
                        for (String key : bundle.keySet()) {
                            json.put(key, wrapObject(bundle.get(key)));
                        }

                        showDialogContext.success(json);
                        showDialogContext = null;
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        showDialogContext.success();
                        showDialogContext = null;
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                FacebookOperationCanceledException e = new FacebookOperationCanceledException();
                handleError(e, showDialogContext);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                Log.e("Activity", String.format("Error: %s", error.toString()));
                handleError(error, showDialogContext);
            }
        });
    } else {
        callbackContext.error("Unable to show dialog");
    }
```

Comment: this article here explains the problems and suggests a solution http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/141/android-cordova-plugin-onactivityresult-is-never-executed-solution

Comment: Yes that's right. But am getting `onActivityResult` callback without any issues. The things is am not getting callback for app invite dialog

Comment: @GautamiBhandary why dont you use the plugin - https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4 which comes out of the box?

Comment: @Gandhi I have tried that also. But same issue persists

Comment: @GautamiBhandary what is the error in the console?